# Using ucwords for non-english characters

Tags: php, regex

Currently, I'm using a ucwords-related function to make capital letters after hyphens, dots and apostrophes:

```
function ucwordsMore ($str){
    $str = ucwords($str);
    $str = str_replace('- ','-',ucwords(str_replace('-','- ',$str)));  // hyphens
    $str = str_replace('. ','.',ucwords(str_replace('.','. ',$str)));  // dots
    $str = preg_replace("/\w[\w']*/e", "ucwords('\\0')", $str);        // apostrophes

    return $str;
}
```

It works fine to english letters. However, non-english letters are not recognized properly. For instance this text:

> La dernière usine française d'accordéons reste à Tulle

is turned into this text:

> La DernièRe Usine FrançAise D'accordéOns Reste à Tulle

But I need it to be:

> La Dernière Usine Française D'Accordéons Reste À Tulle

Any ideas?

Comment: what are english letters really? It's the Latin alphabet. According to your example it seems that the problem lies with accented letters. I'd argue that the A of Accorde'ons is correct though, you can't expect `php` to know that a new word starts without a space before it, and the apostrophe isn't a good delimiter either as it doesn't ALWAYS indicate a word end/start.

Comment: php is pretty much hosed for dealing with Unicode properly; sorry, but some things that are trivial and automatic in say Perl are simply impossible in php.

Answer (score 2):

As @Jon mentioned, you need to `use locale` which implements relationships between upper/lower caseing that affects function calls that use that. Typically it is `LC_CTYPE`.

There are constants for numeric behavior, sorting, monetary and others too. Locale needs to be installed on your machine, or be available via plugins or modules, etc. Read up on that.

I don't know php locale at all so here is a sample in Perl that uses a regex approach different than yours. I couldn't figure out your solution so well, hopefully you can get some ideas from mine.

```
use locale;
use POSIX qw(locale_h);

setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "en_US");

$str = "La dernière usine française d'accordéons reste à Tulle";

$str =~ s/ (?:^|(?<=\s)|(?<=\w-)|(?<=\w\.)|(?<=\w\')) (\w) / uc($1) /xeg;

print "$str\n";
```

Output

```
La Dernière Usine Française D'Accordéons Reste À Tulle
```

Regex

```
Form is s///  find and replace

s/                  # Search

  (?:                  # Group
      ^                   # beginning of string
    | (?<=\s)             # or, lookbehind \s
    | (?<=\w-)            # or, lookbehind \w-
    | (?<=\w\.)           # or, lookbehind \w\.
    | (?<=\w\')           # or, lookbehind \w\'
  )                    # End group
  (\w)                 # Capture group 1, a single word char

/                   # Replace
  uc($1)               # Upercased word char from capt grp 1

/xeg;               # Modifiers x(expanded), e(eval), g(global)
```

Comment: Um, no. You just have to have your strings marked as Unicode strings.  You never have to `use locale` to get correct casing behaviour, except perhaps for Turkic languages, which that won’t help anyway.

Comment: @tchrist - I asumed its not Unicode, thats why locale was used. Perl doesen't understand the concept of Unicode locales anyway, why coerce to Unicode if its not, and couldn't the regex performance degrade because of this? Internally it could be mixed 8-bit encoding with character semantics but I thought Unicode support overhead slows things down. And ah, I am not sure what level of unicode, PHP supports.

Comment: What, you value speed over correctness then, do you? Always normalize legacy encodings to Unicode first. Anyway, Perl supports Unicode locales in the collation module. That’s not in regexes of course, or even casing. Casing is not supposed to be locale-based.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to use [`setlocale`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php) for `LC_CTYPE` before such conversions will be done correctly, but there is also the issue of what encoding your string is in. `ucwords` is only meant to work on single-byte-encoded text.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Kohana UTF8 class - http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/api/UTF8

Comment: Link-only recommendations are low-value and should be written as comments under the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
function mb_ucwords ($string)
{
    return mb_convert_case ($string, MB_CASE_TITLE, 'UTF-8'); 
}
```